# Goat cheese royale definition?

Tags: cheese, language

I have come across a few recipes that envolve a mix of goat cheese, cream and other hard cheeses. They're called 'royale' for some reason. Can anyone define the term 'royale' in this context. 
What makes a royale and if you use any other soft cheese aside from goat, is it still called a royale?

Comment: Can you give an example or pointer?  This does not match the only two culinary definitions of this term that I am able to find.

Comment: http://www.thestaffcanteen.com/image/goats-cheese-royale-beets-celery-watercress-and-caramelised-walnuts/  here is a dish that uses the term. and one more here; http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/goatscheeseroyalandp_88196

Comment: It could be a liberal interpretation of Eierstich (Royale): http://germanfood.about.com/od/soupsandstews/r/eierstich-recipe.htm  The goats cheese recipes seem to produce pudding like textures which may be similar to the texture of a proper royale.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that a "cheese royale" is a fancy name for a custard made with combinations of soft cheeses, cream, eggs and seasoning. From [this recipe:](http://www.aveceric.com/potato-goat-cheese-royale/)

> Whisk together the cream and eggs and season with salt and pepper.
>
> Fill the potatoes with the custard mix and sprinkle chives on top.

As for using other cheeses, I really don't see why not, or why it would be called something different. I would be curious to try it with a sharper cheese for a stronger taste, perhaps make a Spanish/Mexican version (kind of like cheese salsa) or with some finely minced onion and garlic. Use your imagination!

From looking on Google Images for "goat cheese royale" it appears it is most often used in two ways:

### As filling for something like potatoes:

[image: royale-filling]

### As topping for burgers and such:

[image: goat-cheese-burger]

I looked without the "goat" but all I got was pictures of cheese burgers and references from Pulp Fiction!